# How to monitor elastic beanstalk tomcat instance using a profiler

Tags: java, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, profiling, visualvm, jprofiler

I am trying to figure out some performance issues in my spring boot application. A code block is running within a for loop and taking a lot of time(there are no network calls). I want to identify the expensive lines of code within the block.

The war file is deployed on elastic beanstalk and is running in a tomcat web container. I am fairly new to profiling and unable to figure out where to start from. I have read about VisualVM and Jprofiler but not sure how to use them. It would be helpful if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this @deathByChocolate?  I'm in the same boat and getting out of memory heap space errors :-(

Comment: Yes I was able to profile my remote server. However I did not run into memory heap space errors. Can you please paste the error here?

Comment: How did you end up profiling?

Comment: I have shared the steps which I followed in this [doc](https://exclusive-cold-166.notion.site/profiling-in-remote-ec2-instance-using-VisualVM-1470cf3dbeca45f99beb5fda818db20f?pvs=4).